# Specify a random timeout on a http sampler

Tags: apache, jmeter

During load testing I am seeing the majority of my page requests being serviced in less than 2
seconds. I would like to be able to put a random timeout for every http request , Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you can solve your problem with [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion):

> The Duration Assertion tests that each response was received within a given amount of time. Any response that takes longer than the given number of milliseconds (specified by the user) is marked as a failed response.

You can make it random by setting duration to e.g. `${__Random(1000, 2000)}`